# Horrible noise coming from right speaker

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

I am not sure what happened, but my right speaker seems to have acquired some demonic possession and is making a horrible high pitched squealing noise.

Funny thing is any sound Windows  makes sounds fine but if I do a speaker config thing with the (ding, ding, dong) pattern if you get me, the left speaker sounds fine but the right one emits a noises like its trying to do it, but then just sticks on a repeating high pitched noise.

I have creative T6100 if that's any help. Also I use FL studio and any sound on that is horribly distorted again in the right speaker only.

A tiny bit of additional info (maybe unrelated) but I noticed it after Avast tried to scan some game I installed which was error and virus free but maybe it just happened coincidentally at the same time.

Comment: Your computer may have come with a pair of junk speakers, or someone you know may have such a pair or you can pick them up at giveaway prices.  Try another set of speakers to see if the problem is inside your box or related the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking for a short in your speaker connection.

Try unplugging and then re-plugging your connection cable (from the PC and also, if applicable, to the offending speaker).

I have had a similar issue to the one you are describing (although not on only one speaker) because of a plug that was not firmly connected to the output plug.